# How to set environment variables in makefile recipe?

Tags: makefile

Here is a simplified Makefile:

```
all:
    @for (( i = 0; i < 5; ++i )); do \
         var="$$var $$i"; \
         echo $$var; \
     done
    @echo $$var
```

I suppose the value of "var" is "0 1 2 3 4", but the output is:

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
               <--- NOTHING!!!
```

As you can see the last echo is "NOTHING". What is wrong?

Comment: I suspect that each recipe command is invoked in a subshell, so the "var" defined in the first recipe can not be referred in the second line. Is this right?

Comment: Tangentially, using `@` in front of all your rules is an antipattern, and in particular, hampers debugging. Write (the majority of) your rules without it, and use `make -s` if you don't want to see what `make` is doing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution):

> When it is time to execute recipes to update a target, they are executed by invoking a new subshell for each line of the recipe...
>
> **Please note:** this implies that setting shell variables and invoking shell commands such as `cd` that set a context local to each process will not affect the following lines in the recipe. If you want to use `cd` to affect the next statement, put both statements in a single recipe line. Then `make` will invoke one shell to run the entire line, and the shell will execute the statements in sequence.

Try the following:

```
all:
    @for (( i = 0; i < 5; ++i )); do \
         var="$$var $$i"; \
         echo $$var; \
     done; \
    echo $$var
```